# laravel where not in

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-5.3

this is my mysql code

```
SELECT name,lastname FROM employee WHERE employee.id_employee
NOT IN (SELECT assistancea.id_employee FROM assistance WHERE assistance.id_meeting=3)
```

where I'm waiting for a value in number 3
3 is the id_meeting of meeting

```
table employe  
|id_employe|name|lastname

table assistance  
|id_employe|id_meetign|

table meeting  
|id_metting|description|date
```

You could help me make a query from laravel

Answer (score 0):

I wrote it for you.

```
DB::table('employee AS employee')
    ->select(['employee.name','employee.lastname'])
    ->whereNotExists(function ($query) {
            $query->select(DB::raw(1))
                ->from('assistance AS assistance')                      
                ->where('assistance.id_meeting','=',3)                      
                ->whereRaw('employee.id_meeting = assistance.id_meeting');
        })->get();
```